# Wanted: A C++ REST library for integration with JIRA

Tags: open-source, library, c++, rest, jira

I'm seeking recommendations for C++ REST libraries to be able to create a set of tools that connects to JIRA. Perhaps there's even a library especially created for JIRA integrations?

Wishlist:

- Good documentation.
- Uses idiomatic C++ and domain specific styles where applicable. As a reference, the "JSON For Modern C++" library is very easy to use for an experienced C++ programmer and also makes it easy to create objects using JSON style constructs in code.

Not as important:

- Speed

---

Background:
I find JIRA painful to work with and we've used more lightweight, easy to use and fast tools for some time. However, somehow the work we do on Epics etc. needs to go into JIRA so our Scrum master had to manually link tasks etc. I therefore want to create a simple tool that we (software developers) can work in on a daily basis. Whatever goes into this tool can then be sync'ed with JIRA in the background with "all the fields" set to some preset values or according to some logic (TDB). I envision a simple GUI, with Post-It-like notes, and perhaps integrating it with `git` somehow to add notes about what I'm doing that can be collected/grouped and shown as progress on some larger task/epic etc.

```
$ git checkout -b bugfix_unittest_foo
```

This could create a note for me in the system to make it visible what I'm working on the way towards solving a bigger task. It doesn't need a JIRA ticket but can be visualized on the new scrum board I'm thinking of. It could be marked for inclusion in JIRA later or automatically according to some branch naming logic. It will however be done in the background and I as a user will not notice any "lag".

As a developer I would like to never have to use JIRA in my everyday work and preferably not even have to see it on standups.